# making non-reactive call in meteor

Tags: meteor, helper, meteorite, spacebars

I am working on Meteor project. The project is pretty big, so I need to scale it. I will list down a simple example. I have a template of this kind

```
<template name = "test">
    <button class="press">press</button>
    <div>
        {{#each infos}}
            {{this.name}} {{this.age}}
        {{/each}}

    </div>
</template>
```

So we know that whenever the "infos" collection is changed, it will be reflected automatically in my template. But I want this template to be non-reactive.

Meaning, when the page is first loaded, it should show all the "name" and "age" details present in Mongo. After that even if the changes are made in the collection "info", it should not reflect in the template.

I know this sounds really weird. But are there any ways to do it. Like calling ajax when the page is loaded first without using find(), etc etc.
Any suggestions is well accepted.

And thanks in advance to all of u.

Answer (score 3):

Your helper can use a non-reactive [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find). From the docs:

> Any change to the collection that changes the documents in a cursor will trigger a recomputation. To disable this behavior, pass {reactive: false} as an option to find.

Here's an example implementation of the `infos` helper:

```js
Template.test.helpers({
  infos: function() {
    return Infos.find({}, {reactive: false});
  }
});
```

Comment: @avishek I recommend this answer

Comment: Hi @David, thanks. But I want the data to be displayed for the first time. The above sol makes it non reactive completely not even displaying the data for the first time

Comment: This solution makes the assumption that the subscription data is ready prior to the template helper running. If you are using iron-router, you can probably resolve this issue by using waiting on the subscription prior to rendering the route containing this template.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know this is a best solution or not try this

subscribe using `nonReactive`

Docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_nonreactive

```
Tracker.nonreactive(function(){
   Meteor.subscribe("infos");
})
```